# is it possible to scrape data from website which give data while scrolling it using Beautiful Soup of Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to extract data from a scrollable website. Here Number of watches, it is giving me is only 52 because other data of 52 watches is only shown at first scroll. How can I get the all the data.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

# Url from which i will scrap my data
myUrl = "https://www.titan.co.in/shop-online/watches/titan"

'''OPENING THE CONNECTION and GRABBING THE PAGE'''

# Open the website and grap inside my script
openUrl = uReq(myUrl)

# Now i would like to see my graped site
page_html = openUrl.read()

# As it is open connection i need to close it
openUrl.close()



'''HTML PARSING'''

# Parse html
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

# Grab all products
containers = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "product"})
print("Number of watches found:: ", len(containers))

newUrl = []
m = 0
for contains in containers:
    product_page_link_container = contains.find('a', {'class': 'product_page_link'})
    product_detail_url = product_page_link_container['href']
    newUrl.append(myUrl + product_detail_url)

    print(newUrl[m])

    openurl = uReq(newUrl[m])
    pageHtml = openurl.read()
    openurl.close()
    pageSoup = soup(pageHtml, 'html.parser')

    m = m + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling is handled by javascript.
If you want to be able to scrap data that appears while scrolling, you should use a browser emulator like Selenium.